# Regular expression match not working

Tags: regex

Hi I have a regular expression that I'm working on and am trying to figure out why it won't match.

Some sample matches should be:

```
sxbad0ap_ach_refund_inp_0x253_041012.txt
sxbad0ap_ach_refund_inp_a7255_042512.txt
```

The regex:

```
^sxbad0ap_ach_refund_inp_[a-z0-9]{5}_[0-9]{6}\.txt$
```

Link to Regex test: 
http://regexr.com?313ni

Comment: Just enable `multiline` and it will work, as if not caret and dollar will match begin and end of the complete input, not of just a single line

Comment: Oh, and enable `global` so that both test cases are matched, not just one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a testing issue: if you put each string by itself, your regexp matches them flawlessly. Since you put both items in the tester's box, and your regex has `^` and `$` requiring the entire string to match, two strings together do not match.

Answer (score 0):

If I turn the `global` flag on, and remove the `$` (or enable `multiline`) at the end of your regex [it matches fine](http://regexr.com?313no).

`sxbad0ap_ach_refund_inp_[a-z0-9]{5}_[0-9]{6}\.txt`